# issue asprise imaging scan

Tags: java, web, scanning

I have use Aspire scanner using this line of code:

```
File[] files = ScanManager.getDefaultManager().quickScanUsingUI(new File("."), null);
```

in a java web application (servlet and jsp).
But the problem in click scan button from any PC browser  in the network the popup window lunched in the PC that application run , does not appear to user who click scan .

Any suggestion to solve this problem ,  or recommended example for free scanner API working in java web application?

Answer (score 0):

If your Java version at least 7. Use great [File I/O (Featuring NIO.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).
So you can use [Files.walkFileTree()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) method as described at:

- [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)
- [Finding Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)

depending on your needs.